# How to add a continuous sequence (unique identifier) to an array?

Tags: arrays, r

I have an array, similar to this:

```
ar1<- array(rep(1, 91*5*4), dim=c(91, 5, 4))
```

I want to add an extra column at the end of each component (n = 4) that is sequential across all components (I'm not sure if component is the right word).

In this case it would be a sequence from 1 to 364.

The idea behind this is that if the rows are scrambled when I'm messing around with joining data or anything else I would be able to see it and rectify it.

How do I achieve this please?

Comment: Something like `s1 <- split(seq(364), as.integer(gl(364, 91, 364)));ar2 <- array(dim = c(91, 6, 4));for (i in seq_len(dim(ar1)[3])) ar2[,, i] <- cbind(ar1[,, i], s1[[i]])`

Comment: This seems to work. What's easiest way to remove the column once I'm finished please? Sorry I don't work with arrays that much.

Comment: I would keep it in a `list` for easy manipulation instead of array because arrays are rigid in having equal dimensions

Comment: This array will be going into a list, but the row number won't change. If I try and convert it to a list it really messes up the dimensions.

Comment: You can do `lapply(seq_len(dim(ar1)[3]), function(i) ar1[,,i])`

Comment: Sorry so let's say I get to the ar2 stage then do I as.list(ar2) and use that in the lapply statement?

Comment: Re "I would be able to see it" -- you can assign dim names `dimnames(ar1) <- lapply(dim(ar1), seq_len)`. If the rows (or other dimensions) get jumbled, then you'll see it on the outer margins of the display.

Comment: Frank, Thanks. Though I guess this is only across one of the matrix objects not a sequence along all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the following is what you want.
It uses `apply` to add an extra column to each slice defined by the 2nd dimension of the array and after this is done sets the final dimensions correctly.

```
ar2 <- sapply(1:5, function(i){
  new <- seq_len(NROW(ar1[, i, ])) + (i - 1)*NROW(ar1[, i, ])
  cbind(ar1[, i, ], new)
})
dim(ar2) <- c(91, 5, 5)
```

The code above creates a new array, if you want you can rewrite the original one.
To get the original back this will do it.

```
n <- dim(ar2)[2]
ar1_back <- sapply(1:5, function(i){
  ar2[, -n, i]
})
dim(ar1_back) <- c(91, 5, 4)
identical(ar1, ar1_back)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: This works apart from I would like the extra column to be sequential across all dimensions (i.e. not 1 to 91; but 1 to 364). 

Also, out of interest, what is easiest way to remove the column across the array after I have checked nothing is wrong?